# Where's the default video monitor config file?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, video, display-resolution

When I boot my laptop, with an external video monitor attached, the LCD video screen on the laptop comes up in what looks like 1024x768... which I assume is because it's cloning displays, and that the most common setting that either will take is 1024x768.

I'd like it to come up with 1280x800 on the LCD laptop screen, and either no display on the external monitor, or <strike>1920x1080</strike> 1024x768.

There used to be a xorg.conf file, which is where I assume that I might have set this up, but this file doesn't exist in Raring. So... how do I accomplish this?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

By default you don't need xorg.conf any more.
To create a new Xorg.conf make sure you are not running X, then run:

```
sudo Xorg -configure
```

This should generate in your current path a new `xorg.conf` file which you can then move to `/etc/X11`.

Comment: Thanks GuySoft! I couldn't figure out how to quit X, so I rebooted into maintenance mode with a r/w file system, and did the -configure command. I got a fairly large file, but with mostly generic data. It doesn't look like it contains specific display characteristics. Please advise. Cheers, Al